# Does stop over flight cancellation charges twice of normal charges? [Thai Airlines]

Tags: tickets, airlines, cancellations, fees-and-charges

While I am booking for Thai Airlines, I have searches for few others also, but could not come to any conclusion.

Travelling from A->B with stopover in bangkok. Same PNR, etc.

The T&C just says "Permitted with fee XXX $".

I am kind of lost, does this mean if I cancel, I pay XXX, or XXX * 2 since technically these are two flights.

Comment: What exactly is permitted with fee

Comment: these are not two flights, as booking and ticketing concerns technically these are two legs / segments within the same flight / ticket. see my answer.

Comment: Can you provide the fare code? It should appear somewhere on your booking or e-ticket receipt. Also can you clarify the flights involved? That way it might be possible to look up the full detailed fare rules which may be more precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole question depends on the exact terms of the ticket, fare AND the booking agent ( whether it is a site, or a real agent, or even the company itself.

That being said - and speaking from own ( quit big ) experience in changing and cancelling - The Changes / Cancellation fees in almost always for the TICKET as a whole and not the LEG / SEGMENT. I actually can not remember it ever being different..

But if for example, you will make changes to a single LEG inside of the same ticket - different fees / regulations might apply depending, again, on airline. ( for example not change first leg and make longer stay-over with second )

That being said ( again ) the best way is to contact the airline directly.

A small tip addendum:

Being a business traveler, I travel a lot ( 4-8 flights a month ) I find myself changing / cancelling flights almost 70%-80% of the time.  If you are thinking already now about cancellation / changes - or if there is a chance ( even slight ) in you eventually doing so - my own tip and opinion is that it is always better to opt for a higher price ticket with changes permitted. Otherwise in some cases you can simply lose the whole ticket.